# MongoDB squema design for objects with several dates

Tags: mongodb

I'm building an event website. There are 2 types of events:

1. Events with specific dates and times. For example, a theatre show can have a show Jan 10 at 8pm, Jan 11 at 8pm and Jan 13 at 7pm.
2. Events which open a range of hours during several days. For example, an exhibition on a museum can open from Jan 10 to Jan 30 from 10am to 6pm.

I need to save the dates and times so that I can answer the following questions/queries:

1. Which events are going to happen tomorrow from 7pm to 12am?
2. Which events are going to happen this weekend?
3. Which events are about to finish? (the last day is less than one week away)

If we didn't have events type 2, we could have the following squema:

- name
- category
- dates: an array of dates (each day would be on the array)

But because we have events type 2, it has to be different. I thought on having:

- name
- category
- dates: an array of objects like {"2015-01-10 09:00": "2015-01-10 18:00"} with the range of hours of each day.

But I think it's not possible to do a query to solve Question 1 with this squema. Am I wrong?

**How would you structure the data so I could answer those three questions?**

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I tought.

First, on MongoDB you can't have dates as keys.

The model is:

```
{
  "name" : "Bob Dylan",
  "category" : "Exhibition", 
  "dates" : [
    {
      "init" : ISODate("2015-01-08T08:00:00Z"),
      "end" : ISODate("2015-01-08T19:00:00Z") 
    },
    {
      "init" : ISODate("2015-01-09T08:00:00Z"),
      "end" : ISODate("2015-01-09T21:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      "init" : ISODate("2015-01-10T08:00:00Z"),
      "end" : ISODate("2015-01-10T21:00:00Z") 
    }
  ],
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-01-09T16:33:51.338Z")
}
```

And the query is:

```
return Events.find({
    'dates.init' : { $gte: dateInit },
    'dates.end' : { $lte: dateEndPlusOneDay }
  });
```